# how to set Value to to LocalDateTimeTextField?

Tags: java, jfxtras

I use the [JFXtras](http://jfxtras.org/) library in my project and  when i get the value from [LocalDateTimeTextField](http://jfxtras.org/doc/8.0/jfxtras-controls/jfxtras/scene/control/LocalDateTimeTextField.html) it appeared like this 1 juin 2017 01:00:00

My problem is when I want to set value to it. 
I tried many methods but do not worked

```
String date="1 juin 2017 17:00:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime localDate = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
fieldDate.setDisplayedLocalDateTime(localDate);
```

I debug my broject and give me the error in this line

```
 LocalDateTime localDate = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
```

Comment: ***....but do not worked...*** how doesnt work? is throwing an exception, is setting another value, is setting nothing at all????

Comment: Never used it (nor JavaFX), but I guess this is the method you want: http://jfxtras.org/doc/8.0/jfxtras-controls/jfxtras/scene/control/LocalDateTimeTextField.html#setLocalDateTime-java.time.LocalDateTime-. Note that your pattern is incorrect. hh should be HH.

Comment: it giv me en error in this line           LocalDateTime localDate = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);

Comment: @amirouche and the error is...

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with JavaFX or JFXtras. Your problem is in parsing a string to LocalDateTime, which is a standard Java 8 class.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

No matter how the LocalDateTime is formatted per default, you still need to define a pattern that matches. For example the "MMM" requires a three letter month, not a four letter one.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html

Try adding an M and replace the hh with HH:
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse("1 April 2017 17:00:00")